# ASP.NET MVC3 client side state management

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side, state-management

I have 2 Views in my MVC3 application. One View creates a cookie via JavaScript, and I'm trying to access it in another View.But it shows up as 'undefined'. Why so? Also, I wanted to know if there are any client side state management options in ASP.NET MVC3 besides Cookies?

Comment: Why are you accessing cookies in your *views*? Do you have cookie setting/reading code you can show us? and cookies are your best general-purpose mechanism for *small amounts* of state. You may need to look into HTML5 options for (slightly) more.

Comment: The data I'm trying to store are small strings. the methods which i have used for cookie creation and retrieval are given here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: You should show us the code snippet which creates the cookie as well as the one reading the cookie.

Comment: Code samples would help as according to the link you posted it looks straight forward. Might be something wrong in the code.

Comment: Ew a w3schools link.... :(  You'd be better of looking at code samples on the http://www.asp.net/mvc site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround (not exactly what I was looking for though) for the problem.I used the Session object to store my data and then retrieved the session in a string variable under @{ } block in my razor View. I then accessed the C# variable in my JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage:

```
window.localStorage["test"] = "Hello World!";
```

Comment: Thanks,but Iam not supposed to use any HTML5 functionality as of now in my project :(